# android setOnClickListener it doesn't work

Tags: android, onclicklistener

Nothing happens when i press to `button`. How can i fix that. I'm new on Java and I couldn't find my mistake.
[click to see the video](https://youtu.be/ecypDV7z5zU)

```
package com.example.tolgadogan.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;

public class clickj extends Activity {

    Button wrt;
    TextView txt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        wrt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        wrt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txt.setText("This is a test text...");
            }
        });

    }
}
```

And Also XML code is here;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.tolgadogan.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="59dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I did everything and exactly same code with what i see in tutorial videos but it doesn't work when i press to `button`.

Comment: you have linked a youtube video?!?! please post your code instead

Comment: Please do not show a link to indicate regarding your problem instead add your code with your answer.

Comment: All right, I added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because that view is connected with the `MainActivity`. But you add the `onClick` in the otherActivity(`SecondActivity`) and you set the same view to that activity as well. When you run the app activity with the `LAUNCHER` starts the app which is your `MainActivity`.It has a view.But no click events.

Go with one of these options and add some music to your video :P

1. Add your click events in your `MainActivity`
2. Make your `SecondActivity` starts first by making it the launcher activity
3. Call  `SecondActivity` from your `MainActivity`  using an `intent`.Then you can perform any actions that you have in that activity

This is the launcher check it in your manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Then your click will work

Comment: It worked, thanks... By the way next time i will add some music to my video . :P :D